# Multi Commodity VRP Time Windows Paper

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, gurobi, vehicle-routing, logistics

I have been wondering is there any paper that who discuss multi commodity with four index/indices like this formulation below:
$$
\begin{gathered}
\sum_{k} \sum_{c} F_{j, j, c, k}=1 \quad \forall j \\
\sum_{i} F_{i, j, c, k}=\sum_{i} F_{j, i, c, k} \quad \forall c, j, k \\
\sum_{i, j, c, k} F_{i, j, c, k}=q_{i} \quad \forall i \\
\sum_{i, j, c, k} F_{i, j, c, k} \leq Q * x_{i, j, k} \quad \forall i, j, c, k
\end{gathered}
$$

Comment: What are the different variables/parameters/sets in your model?

Comment: @JorisKinable what do you mean?